# How to access a variable name in ColdFusion that contains a special character

Tags: variables, coldfusion, cfhttp

For example I have the following bit of code:

```
<cfhttp url="FileURL" method="get" result="HTTPResult" timeout="5" />
```

And I want to do this:

```
<cfoutput>
    #HTTPResult.ResponseHeader.content-type#
</cfoutput>
```

However ColdFusion will see the dash `-` as an operator and try to subtract variables "HTTPResult.ResponseHeader.content" from "type", and neither exists. Is there a direct way to access the "content-type" variable or do I need to jump through hoops to fetch it out of the header variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
HTTPResult.ResponseHeader["content-type"]
```

Comment: That's the ticket! But I thought using the brackets around it would try and make it access it as part of an array?

Comment: @DefconRhall nope. That's the alternate way to fetching value from struct, and the key can now be dynamic like `HTTPResult.ResponseHeader[key]`, where `key="content-type"`. :)

Comment: `ResponseHeader` is a structure. CF supports the usage of associative array notation with structures. http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=arrayStruct_07.html

Comment: associative array notation lets you get away with all sorts of "bad things", like variable names that start with a numeric value, or have an illegal character in them. or something like `myVar[ foo & "bar" ]`, where `myVar` is a struct and _something_bar is a key.