# Variable name starting with @ causes error: Invalid token @ found on line X at column Y

Tags: xml, coldfusion, weather-api

I am trying to format a ColdFusion page with data from the National Weather Service API (NOAA).  Using the following ColdFusion code I am able to dump the data.

```
<cfhttp url="https://api.weather.gov/alerts/active/zone/ANZ335" result="weather">
<cfhttpparam name="accept" type="header" value="application/ld+json">
</cfhttp>
<cfset alerts = deserializeJSON(#weather.filecontent#) />
```

In the dump, I can XML data that uses a "@" character to name the nodes.
[image: Dump of XML Data]

However, ColdFusion does not like the `@` sign when you try to output the values.  For example:

```
#arraylen(alerts.@graph)#
```

Causes an *"Invalid token @ found on line X..."* error.

Any ideas on how I can get by this issue?

Comment: (Know there is already a few answers on this, but don't have time to search for duplicate threads now) In short, for keys with invalid variable names, use associative array notation: `structName["keyNameInQuotes"]` or... `alerts["@graph"]`

Comment: When using dot notation, variable names must follow [CF variable naming rules](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/using-coldfusion-variables/creating-variables.html): *"A variable name must begin with a letter, underscore, or Unicode currency symbol...."*.

Comment: @Ageax.  Outstanding.  Beginners mistake.  Thanks

Comment: @Ageax You should move this comment down as an answer.

Comment: @SiriusPhil  And to add on, if you needed to drill way down, you can also kinda mix the different notations: `alerts["@graph"][1].references[1]["@id"]`. Even though I use a quoted name for `@graph1`, I can still use dot-notation to point to `references` and then back to quoted-notation for `@id` (and with the positional-notation for the array elements).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a variable name in coldfusion that contains a special character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312226/how-to-access-a-variable-name-in-coldfusion-that-contains-a-special-character)

Comment: @Shawn - Yeah, I was going to but wanted to search for a duplicate thread first. Surprisingly, I didn't find a good fit, so I'll post an answer and edit the question title to make it a better reference for similar questions.

Comment: @SamM - Good spot. I'd seen that but overlooked it as different because the code wasn't visible. Wish I could update the existing answer to add more info and make it more generic - but it'd get rejected as "too drastic".

Answer (score 3):

When using dot notation, variable names must adhere to [CF's variable naming rules](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/using-coldfusion-variables/creating-variables.html). In particular:

> A variable name must begin with a letter, underscore, or Unicode
>   currency symbol....

For structure keys with invalid variable names, use associative array notation:

```
structName["keyNameInQuotes"]
```

... or more specifically:

```
 alerts["@graph"]
```

As [@Shawn mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52248304/noaa-weather-api-causing-coldfusion-error/52267743#comment91468427_52248304), you can also mix dot notation with associative array notation. So these are valid as well:

```
variables.alerts["@graphs"]
variables["alerts"]["@graphs"]
```

Comment: Nothing to do with the error, but no need for the `#` signs when deserializing the result. Just use `<cfset alerts = deserializeJSON(weather.filecontent) /> `